# How do I unsubscribe or change a changefeed in rethinkdb?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

Is there a way to unsubscribe or change an existing changefeed observer in rethinkdb?  Setting the return value of the changes() function to null doesn't seem to do anything, is there a unsubscribe() function?

What I'd ideally like to do is change one of the index filter parameters (favorites) after the changefeed is created (since changefeeds on joins don't work and I have to change the feed if the underlying favorites collection changes).

Here is the sample code in javascript

```
  var observer = r.table("users")
                 .getAll(r.args(favorites), {index:"name"})
                 .changes().then(function(results) {


            results.each(function(err,row) {
              if (err) console.error(err);
              var prefix = row.new_val ? 'added' : 'deleted';
              var msg =  row.new_val ?  row.new_val :  row.old_val;
              console.log(prefix + ': ' +  msg.name);
          });

      });

 observer = null; //what do I do there to have it stop observing or unsubscribe... or change the subscription to something else.. say adding a filter or changing a filter?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know what library are you using for JS. With rethinkdb + rethinkdb-pool you can use this syntaxes:

```
r.table("users").getAll(r.args(favorites), {index:"name"})
                .changes().run(connection, function(err, cursor) {


     cursor.each(function(err,row) {
         if (err) console.error(err);
         var prefix = row.new_val ? 'added' : 'deleted';
         var msg =  row.new_val ?  row.new_val :  row.old_val;
         console.log(prefix + ': ' +  msg.name);
     });
}
```

So after that you can just [close cursor](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/close-cursor/) to stop receiving changes:

```
cursor.close();
```

Or you can [close connection](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/close/), and it will automatically close all cursors associated with a connection:

```
connection.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the JS driver in particular, but generally you should receive a cursor at some point, and calling `close` on that cursor will close the changefeed.  (I'm not sure in the API above whether `observer` or `results` is the cursor, but if you print their types you should be able to see.)